# Image is not being uploaded on server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am using Laravel 5.8 for uploading the file on the server through ajax but don't understand what's going wrong. All the other data are being sent except the input file.

hasFile() method always returns false and input::file() returns null.

I know this question has been asked many times but none of the solutions worked for me.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#updateUser').click(function(){

    var form = $('#updateForm');

    var postData = new FormData($("#updateForm")[0]);

    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        cache : false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: form.attr('method'),
        dataType: 'json',
        data: postData,
        success : function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
})
```

})

**view file**

```
<form id="updateForm" class="ui form register-form"  method="POST" action="{{ route('updateUserProfile') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf

    <div class="field">
        <label>Profile Photo</label>
        <div class="two fields">
            <div class="field">
                <img src="{{ $current_user->profile_photo }}">
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <input type="file" name="profile_photo" placeholder="Profile Photo" class="" multiple="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**controller file**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use Auth;
use App\Functions;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\File;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;


public function updateUserProfile(Request $request)
{
    $validators = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'first_name'    => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'last_name'     => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email'         => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255'],
        'password'      => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        'mobile_no'     => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'dob'           => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'gender'        => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'country_id'    => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        //'profile_photo' => ['image', 'mime_content_type(jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg)', 'max:1024'],
        'profile_photo' => 'image'|'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
    ]);

    if ($validators->fails()) {
        $result['success'] = false;
        $result['messages'] = $validators->errors()->all();

        return json_encode($result);
    }

    var_dump(input::file('profile_photo'));
    var_dump($request->hasFile('profile_photo'));
}
```

Comment: Have you already checked the php.ini regarding file uploads (allowed, max size, etc)?

Comment: can you write this statement var_dump(input::file('profile_photo'));
    var_dump($request->hasFile('profile_photo')); above the $validators->file

Comment: Can you explain how it's not working i.e. what errors you're getting (if any), what http status is being returned etc.?

Comment: Put this line var_dump($request->file('profile_photo')) into your code

Comment: I have already checked the php.ini file. my max_upload_size = 24M and post_max_size = 64M

Answer (score -1):

Put this line var_dump($request->file('profile_photo')) into your code

Comment: Please add this as a comment and not an answer.